# Email validation using javascript with a custom message below the input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple form with email input field. I would like to get an error below the field when the email input is left empty which my code already does.
However, I would like a message to appear below the input field if the email is not validated. Currently, I can only get the error message (email is invalid) at all times.
So basically a user either leaves the input empty and get an error message (you must type in an email), or does not provide a valid email then gets a another error message.

```js
const email = document.querySelector('.email');
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const emailMessage = document.querySelector('.empty-email-message');
const errorEmail = document.querySelector('.invalid-email-message');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  if (!email.value) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   emailMessage.style.display = 'none';
    // }, 1000);
    emailMessage.innerHTML = 'You must type in an email';
  } else {
    emailMessage.innerHTML = '';
    // return true;
  }
});

if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email.value)) {
  errorEmail.value = '';
} else {
  errorEmail.value = 'email is invalid';
}
```

```html
 <form class="form" id="form" action="submit">
    <input class="email" type="email" />
    <button class="submit-email" type="submit">Go</button>
    <!-- dont use id -->
    <p class="empty-email-message"></p>
    <p class="invalid-email-message"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned the condition outside of the function scope, so make it inside
and check first whether the email has value,

If it has value then check for `regex match`.

If regex match doesn't match with input provided, then display the error message,
`errorEmail.textContent = 'email is invalid';` and makue sure that you are making the empty error message to `''` empty string..

If you want to make the validation on user input, then you can follow this approach https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/WNvxQPq

Note:

**Unless you are replacing HTML element, don't use innerHTML, instead use textContent if you are going to replace only text.**

```js
const email = document.querySelector('.email');
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const emailMessage = document.querySelector('.empty-email-message');
const errorEmail = document.querySelector('.invalid-email-message');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    if(email.value){
    const regexMatch = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email.value);
    if (regexMatch) {
          errorEmail.textContent = '';
        } else {
          e.preventDefault();
          errorEmail.textContent = 'email is invalid';
          emailMessage.textContent = "";
        }
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      emailMessage.textContent = 'You must type in an email';
      errorEmail.textContent = "";
    }
});
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form" action="submit">
    <input class="email" type="email" />
    <button class="submit-email" type="submit">Go</button>
    <!-- dont use id -->
    <p class="empty-email-message"></p>
    <p class="invalid-email-message"></p>
 </form>
```

Comment: Just a question, why did you need to change the email input type to text?

Comment: @HesamAlavi, Sorry for that, I have modified it for testing purpose as there was browser validation happens for ```type="email"``` and forgot to revert back.. Edited the answer now with type email..

Comment: No problem, but if it is type="email", wouldn't the browser validation override the code? Is there any way around it?

Comment: @HesamAlavi, If you want to override the default browser validation, the use ```type="text"``` because you already check for the valid email through ```regex```..  So i would prefer you can use ```type="text"``` but if you want browser validation also coupled then use ```type="email"```..

Comment: Also I would like you to take look at https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/WNvxQPq where with type email, I have overwritten browser validation with input event listener.. Here you will see only your email validation with ```type="email"``` ..

Comment: That does work. The email validation error does come up before the form is submitted though. I tried paying around with different eventlistener forms but not successful. If the code could work just like it did when the type of text, but with the type email that would be amazing. Using invalid works, but the browser default message also shows.